# Как сделать type guard для массива?

Tags: typescript, типы

Есть массив, который может быть двух типов, например `I1[] | I2[]` (интерфейсы).
Как правильно описать функцию `isI1`, если массив может быть пустым, а тип проверить нужно (также тип можно передать женериком, но я пока не смог разобраться, как это использовать для гуарда)

```typescript
export function isI1<T>(
  paths: I1[] | I2[] | T[] //Может быть пустым
): paths is I1[] {
  return
}
```

Comment: если массив пустой - в нем может быть что угодно ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

По пустому массиву нельзя понять какого он типа, но это и не нужно. С точки зрения структурной типизации `[]` является подмножеством любого массива, поэтому верным будет реализовать тайпгард так:

```typescript
function isI1(value: I1[] | I2[]): value is I1[] {
    if (value.length == 0) return true

    // Далее проверка для первого элемента
}
```